# How to search through a hash for a specific key if the key is a string

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I can't find a specific key in a hash. From here,

```
titles = {'book1' => 396, 'book2' => 346}
print 'What title would you like to search for? '
item = gets.chomp
```

I need to search for the item in the hash. Please let me know how. I found other methods, but they don't work when the key is a string.

Comment: Please show a working example of what doesn't work for you.

Comment: Does `titles[item]` work?

Comment: @SagarPandya I added the context of my program. Hope it helps!

Comment: @tadman So you are saying to do something like: puts titles[item]

Comment: That's the idea. If you type in the key correctly that will give you the answer.

Comment: @tadman Ok! Thank you so much

Comment: If you're learning Ruby it really helps to have a good reference book on hand at all times. The [Pickaxe book](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) is a good place to start. The online version is older but still very good. Newer versions in print or ebook contain more up-to-date advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code:

```
puts titles[item]
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify the intended behaviour, when the user enters a key which is not present in the hash.

```
titles[item]
```

returns the associated value if `item` is a key in the hash, and returns nil otherwise.

Note also that you can test with `titles.has_key?(item)`, whether the key exists in the hash. This is useful if you have a hash where some of the values can be nil.